# Adding obstacles & collision to canvas game

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

I am trying to add some obstacles to the canvas game that I've got but something seems to be wrong and I can't seem to put my finger on it.

I just want some simple walls here and there to make the game harder and collision with the walls (so that if the player hits the wall it's game over).

```js
var
    // variables
    COLS = 25, // Columns
    ROWS = 25, // Rows
    EMPTY = 0, // Empty Cell
    SNAKE = 1, // Snake
    FRUIT = 2, // Fruit
    LEFT  = 0, // left direction (key)
    UP    = 1, // up direction (key)
    RIGHT = 2, // right direction (key)
    DOWN  = 3, // down direction (key)
    KEY_LEFT  = 37, // key codes for keyboard input (Codes can be found online)
    KEY_UP    = 38, // key codes for keyboard input (Codes can be found online)
    KEY_RIGHT = 39, // key codes for keyboard input (Codes can be found online)
    KEY_DOWN  = 40, // key codes for keyboard input (Codes can be found online)
    obstacle =  [[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0]],
        //        [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
        //        [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
        //        [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
        //        [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0]],
               
    
    // Objects 
    canvas,   // Canvas
    ctx,   // Canvas render
    keystate, // Key inputs
    frames,   // frames per second
    score;   // player score
    
    grid = {
     width: null,  // Amount of columns 
     height: null, // Amount of rows
     _grid: null,  // Array
     init: function(d, c, r) { // initiation with direction, columns and rows.
      this.width = c; // Set width to number of columns (c)
      this.height = r;  // set height to number of rows (r)
            this._grid = []; // Initiate grid with empty array
      for (var x=0; x < c; x++) {
       this._grid.push([]); 
       for (var y=0; y < r; y++) {
        this._grid[x].push(d); // set current column and push new value for each row in column
       }
      }
     },
     set: function(val, x, y) { // set values for the grid cells with x and y position 
      this._grid[x][y] = val;
     },
     
     get: function(x, y) { // get the value of x and y position
      return this._grid[x][y];
     }
        
    }
    
    snake = { // Creating snake
     direction: null, // Direction of snake
     last: null,   // last element in queue pointer
     _queue: null,  // queue array
    
        // Sets start position of snake, same initiation method as before
     init: function(d, x, y) {
      this.direction = d; // Direction set to d
      this._queue = []; // Another empty queue array
      this.insert(x, y); // Inserting x & y position
     },
        
        // Insert method that adds elements to queue with x and y position
     insert: function(x, y) {
      this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y}); // unshift prepends an element to array
      this.last = this._queue[0];
     },
     
        // Remove function to remove and return element to queue 
     remove: function() {
      return this._queue.pop(); // pop returns the last element of array
     }
    };
    
function obstacle() {
  empty.push({obstacle});

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(obstacle);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#7a26ce";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function setFood() { // Food for hungry snake 
  var empty = []; // tracks all empty places in the grid
  // for loop to find all empty cells in grid
  for (var x=0; x < grid.width; x++) {
    for (var y=0; y < grid.height; y++) {
      if (grid.get(x, y) === EMPTY) {
        empty.push({x:x, y:y});
      }
    }
  }
  // variable randomposition to pick random empty cell
  var randpos = empty[Math.round(Math.random()*(empty.length - 1))];
  grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);
}

function main() { // call all the functions that we will use in the game
  // canvas 
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = COLS*20;  // Sets canvas width to columns * 20 
  canvas.height = ROWS*20; // Sets canvas height to columns * 20 
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  document.body.appendChild(canvas); // Adds canvas element to the body of the document
  ctx.font = "12px sans-serif"; // font 
  frames = 0;
  keystate = {};

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) { // Track all keyboard input
    keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
  });
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) { // Track all keyboard input
    delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
  });

  init(); // Initiate Game Loop 
  loop(); // Start Game Loop 
}

function init() { // Reset and intiate game objects
  score = 0; // set start score to 0
  grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);


  var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
  snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y); // Start direction
  grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);
  setFood();
  grid._grid = grid._grid.concat(obstacle);
}

function loop() { // Game loop for rendering and objects
  update();
  draw();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas); // Canvas will call loop function when it needs to redraw
}

function update() { // update function
  frames++;
  // Keyboard input
  if (keystate[KEY_LEFT] && snake.direction !== RIGHT) {
    snake.direction = LEFT;
  }
  if (keystate[KEY_UP] && snake.direction !== DOWN) {
    snake.direction = UP;
  }
  if (keystate[KEY_RIGHT] && snake.direction !== LEFT) {
    snake.direction = RIGHT;
  }
  if (keystate[KEY_DOWN] && snake.direction !== UP) {
    snake.direction = DOWN;
  }
  // Update game every 5 frames.
  if (frames%5 === 0) {
    // last element from the snake queue 
    var nx = snake.last.x;
    var ny = snake.last.y;
    // Updating the position of snake depending on the direction it is heading
    switch (snake.direction) {
      case LEFT:
        nx--;
        break;
      case UP:
        ny--;
        break;
      case RIGHT:
        nx++;
        break;
      case DOWN:
        ny++;
        break;
    }
    // if statement checking conditions whether game should keep running or reset aka game over
    if (0 > nx || nx > grid.width-1  ||
        0 > ny || ny > grid.height-1 ||
        grid.get(nx, ny) === SNAKE
       ) {
      return init();

    }
    // Checks the new position of the snake and if it's on a fruit item or not.
    if (grid.get(nx, ny) === FRUIT) {
      // If it is on a fruit item it will increase your score and create a new food in a random cell.
      score++;
      setFood();

    } else {
      // Takes out the tail (first item) from queue and removes identifier from the grid.
      var tail = snake.remove();
      grid.set(EMPTY, tail.x, tail.y);

    }

    // Snake identifier that is created at the new position and is added to the queue 
    grid.set(SNAKE, nx, ny);
    snake.insert(nx, ny);

  }
}

function draw() { // render grid to canvas
  var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;  // Calculate tile width
  var th = canvas.height/grid.height; // Calculate tile height

  for (var x=0; x < grid.width; x++) { // for-loop loops through entire grid to draw cells
    for (var y=0; y < grid.height; y++) {
      // Depending on the identifier of each cell sets certain fillstyle defined below. 
      switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
        case EMPTY:
          ctx.fillStyle = "#5a5a5a";
          break;
        case SNAKE:
          ctx.fillStyle = "#B54548";
          break;
        case FRUIT:
          ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
          break;
        case obstacle:
          ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
          break;
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, tw, th);
    }
  }
  // Change fillstyle and show score on the screen.
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillText("SCORE: " + score, 10, canvas.height-10);
}
// Game Start!
main();
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

or **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg26rt42/)**.

Comment: Not that this isn't a valid question for SO, but I think you might find better answers and visibility for it over at the game dev SO - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have been making games with collisions for a while now, and I find that using a collision map is the easiest way, instead of making one object that stores all entities at once. Here's an example:

```
var collisions = [];
function addCollision(x,y){
    if(typeof collisions[x] == "undefined")collisions[x] = []; //If the row is empty, create it
    collisions[x][y] = true;                                   //Set the row and column to true
};
function checkCollision(x,y){
    return (typeof collisions[x] != "undefined")?//If the row is undefined, there's nothing in it, so return false
    ((typeof collisions[x][y] != "undefined")    //If not, but the column is undefined, return false
    ?true:false):false;                          //If the row and column is true, return true.
};
```

Now, `addCollision(x,y)` will put a new piece to collide with, and `checkCollision(x,y)` will see there is anything at x,y.

This is good for (relatively) small maps, as a large one will eat up a lot of memory. I have been able to do 500x500, but I'm not sure what the max size is.